# Python Error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'flatten'

Tags: python, arrays, linear-regression, series

I'm very new to Python and I'm trying to walk through a fairly simple linear regression model.

When I try and run this line of code I get the error 'Series' object has no attribute 'flatten'

```
df4= pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test.flatten(), 'Predicted': y_pred.flatten()})
```

As my values are outputs of regression I'm fairly certain it was an array and nowhere in my code do I create a series. Is there a way to turn this into an array so I can use the flatten function?

I've tried using .values which throws this error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'

```
df4= pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test.values.flatten(), 'Predicted': y_pred.values.flatten()})
```

Y_test definition

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

X & Y definition
    X = df2[["MonthYear"]] y = df2["HC"]

The data is all numeric & looks like:
HC    MonthYear
567       1
597       2
652       3

Comment: can you post the code snippets where y_test is defined

Comment: Perhaps you did not turn your `y_test` to an array. Use flatten only for `ypred`, which is presumably the output of the regressor

Comment: @mathewgunther X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

Comment: In newer versions of `sklearn`, `train_test_split` returns objects of the same type as the input.

Comment: Can you do the same for X and y?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have convert these series y_test and y_pred to numpy array to using the flatten function, i got the same problem but fixed it using the following fix:

1) Use y_test.shape. To find out the shape of your dataframe series i.e. in your case y_test and y_pred.

2) Use the number of rows and columns found out by shape to reshape this data frame column or series to a Numpy array. Because flatten is a function of Numpy array.

3) Then use your flatten function, it would work.

The code is given below. 1. Step one: test.shape 2. Step two (reshape) : test = test.values.reshape(1,4069) 3. df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': test.flatten(), 'Predicted': pred.flatten()})

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
y_test = np.array(list(y_test))
y_pred = np.array(y_pred)
df4= pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test.flatten(), 'Predicted': y_pred.flatten()})
```

This should solve your problem.